# Javascript: Creating string by different methods

Tags: javascript

On Firebug:

```
>>> str1 = String('String One');
"String One"
typeof(str1);
"string"

>>> str2 = new String('String Two');
String { 0="S", 1="t", 2="r", more...}
typeof(str2);
"object"
```

My Question is what is the difference between both technique?
What is the advantage of one over the other?

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects.

Answer (score 2):

The only real difference is that using `new String()`, you get an object that extends from `Object`, meaning that this code works:

```
var foo = new String( 'bar' );
foo.property = 42;
```

whereas this doesn't:

```
var foo = 'bar';
foo.property = 42;
```

It's also sometimes useful if you need to get a string:

```
var foo = new String( 21*2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much of an advantage one way or the other because almost nobody creates a string this way they just declare `var a = 'This is a string';`  This is similar to the fact that the accepted way to create an array is not `var a = new Array()` but `var a = []`.  I guess the first way might have an advantage because it labeled as a string instead of an object, but

```
var a = 'This is a string';
typeof(a);//returns string
```

Comment: i dont know using square brackets as the array constructor is `accepted` over new Array(), it just easer :}

Answer (score 0):

in the first example you got the **return type of String()**;
in the second you got the **type of String() itself** / or more precisely the type of the new String() instance.

more info:
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_String.asp
 http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: eww, don't like to w3schools bro

Answer (score 0):

The `new String` wrapper is a wart put into the language a long time ago to please the Java folks. As you might have already noticed, those inconsistencies are good reasons why it is not a widely recommended practice today.

Meanwhile, using `String(something)` is useful if you want to convert values to strings but most people just use the shorter `''+something` instead.

`String('string')` is unecessary, since `'string'` already is a string.

**tldr** avoid `new String` and other wrappers like `new Array` and `new Number` like the plague.